# ObjC / Clang optimizations casing crash if not -O0

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm-clang

What optimizations does `clang` do in `-O1`? The piece of code I'm trying to debug fails as soon as apparently any optimization is performed. Is `-O1` a collection of flags that I could try one by one?

Comment: Where/how does it crash?

Comment: I vote for undefined/unspecified behavior somewhere in your program: you get lucky when optimization is turned off. Look for memory allocations / initialization issues.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to narrow down, which is why it would be helpful if I could selectively switch on optimizations to narrow the problem further down.

Comment: Have you run the static analyzer against the code?

Comment: Yep, didn't turn up anything.